# Ponto e Virgula ';' inicio da pagina Laravel

Tags: laravel, layout

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um projeto com Laravel 5.1 e estou com um problema relacionado a um sinal de ';' no inicio da página.

Já apaguei todo o código do layout padrão, ou seja, sem nenhum HTML na pagina, ela ainda mostra o sinal de ';'. Já vasculhei todo o código, mas nada de encontrar.

Segue:

```
<body style="background: url(/imagens/plano_fundo.jpg) repeat;">;
</body>
```

Volto a repetir. Se eu excluir todo o código da pagina, esse ';' ainda irá aparecer.
Alguém já teve esse problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É exatamente esse código que está na sua página? Porque nesse código existe um ";" dentro da tag body, especificamente logo depois do sinal ">".
Seria esse o problema?

Answer (score 0):

Realmente

```
<body style="background: url(/imagens/plano_fundo.jpg) repeat;">";" esse ponto e virgula não deveria esta aqui.
</body>
```